# Patch for create_function() causes problems in PHP 7.3.6

Tags: php, patch, create-function

I am trying to replace deprecated "create_function" in a CMS. I already found a lot of answers for this topic. However, the patch I used resulted in even more trouble and I am not really firm in working on this level of PHP functions. Therefore I would be really happy, if someone could help me out here.

I changed

```
$list->setColumnFormat('active', 'custom', create_function(
  '$params',
  'global $I18N;
   $list = $params["list"];
   return $list->getValue("active") == 1 ? $I18N->msg("yes") : $I18N->msg("no");'
));
```

to

```
$list->setColumnFormat('active', 'custom', function($params) {
  global $I18N; 
  $list = $params["list"]; 
  return $list->getValue("active") == 1 ? $I18N->msg("yes") : $I18N->msg("no");
});
```

However then - instead of just a "deprecated" message - I get

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string in [filename] on line 155

line 155 is:

```
trigger_error('rexCallFunc: Using of an unexpected function var "'.$function.'"!');
```

var_dump($function) gives:

```
object(Closure)#16 (1) { ["parameter"]=> array(1) { ["$params"]=> string(10) "" } }
```

If I comment this line 155 out, I also get:

> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '' not found or invalid function name in [the same filename] on line 163

line 163 is:

```
return call_user_func($func, $params);
```

var_dump($func) gives:

```
string(0) ""
```

**Does anybody have an idea what this is about and how it can be solved?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create_function` [returns a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php#refsect1-function.create-function-returnvalues) with the name of an "anonymous" function, not an anonymous function. If you want to avoid changing the `setColumnFormat()` method, you'll need to create a named function rather than an anonymous function, and pass that name as a string that `setColumnFormat()` can use in `call_user_func()`.

```
function patchFunction($params) {
    global $I18N; 
    $list = $params["list"]; 
    return $list->getValue("active") == 1 ? $I18N->msg("yes") : $I18N->msg("no");
}

$list->setColumnFormat('active', 'custom', 'patchFunction');
```